# TCPDF Maximum execution time exceed 30 seconds

Tags: php, tcpdf

Can somebody please help me how to fix this error. I have a pdf page and I made a custom page size and made it landscape.

But when I run the page. It has an error saying "Maximum execution time exceeded 30 seconds in tcpdf.php line 18385

It only appears when I uploaded it in the server.

But when I use the program through remote it runs.

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue as well on some content-heavy PDFs. PHP by default only allows a maximum execution time of 30 seconds.

You can increase this time in the `php.ini` file by changing the following line:

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

to

```
max_execution_time = 60
```

or adding this to the top of your script file.

```
set_time_limit(60);
```

60 seconds should be enough time for TCPDF to do what it needs to do but you may need to increase it further. Be careful with increasing it too much, however, as it can cause issues.

**NOTE:** If you're reaching the maximum execution time due to an infinite loop, this won't change anything.

Comment: when I run it through remote, there is no error but when in server the error appears. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by running it through remote? Do you mean running it directly through ssh using `php phpfile.php`? If so, that uses a different php.ini, that one will be the php-cli php.ini rather than the standard php.ini

Comment: Yes, using the other machine. But when I uploaded it to the server, it doesn't work.

Comment: What does phpinfo() say for max_execution_time? When you run the script via ssh, your php-cli php.ini file may not have any extra modules enabled which could cause it to complete faster.

Comment: Make a php file in your html directory, make the contents `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open it in your browser. It should give you a bunch of information about your php installation and configuration. Press `ctrl`+`f` and search for "max_execution_time" and it should have the number next to it listed in seconds. To check for enabled modules, in the php.ini files there will be lines like this: `extension=module.so`.

Comment: How it affcets the tcpdf? Before, it has no error, but when I updated it, I don't know what causes the error

Comment: It depends on the root cause of the problem. As I said before, PHP has a maximum execution time of 30 seconds by default which means that any scripts will stop if they run for 30 seconds. Generating PDFs can take a bit of time depending on the content they have to generate. So if the generation script runs for 30 seconds, PHP will stop it and return the error your received. You can try to generate a very small PDF file with only a few lines of text to see if that has the same problem.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that you will need to restart the webserver after changing the php.ini file.

Comment: Yes, I've tried changing it to 300 but same result.

Comment: Does it work if you try to generate a small pdf with just a few words of text?

Comment: Yes. it works. Does it affect the generation of pdf?

Comment: There's this one pdf page that is not working. Lots of column and almost 600 rows to be generated as table.

Comment: Try to generate the PDF without the table and see if that works. If it does, then it's definitely the table that is the problem. Also double check the syntax of the table and make sure that each tag is closed properly. It can cause issues if there are unclosed tags. It may also be worthwhile to see if you can break the table up into smaller segments

Comment: Can I generate a 1000+ rows in tcpdf?

Comment: We tried to make the max execution time. Does it affect the whole softwarE? I mean, Does this value will be the normal loading time?

Comment: Good to hear :) With the max execution time, it will change it for anything running off that server. It won't affect the coding or standard run time, it will just mean that scripts can run longer before PHP will abort them for taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ini_set("you php config",0);`